# Check for negative numbers with TryParse

Tags: c#, tryparse

Is it possible to check for negative number using `Int32.TryParse`?

```
int defaultTop;
displayTop = (Int32.TryParse(DisplayTop, out defaultTop) ? Convert.ToInt32(DisplayTop) : 1000 );
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If it is a valid integer then it will be converted, regardless of if it is negative or positive. If it is not a valid Int then it will fail...

Comment: Not with TryParse directly. But why not just check defaultTop itself after it's been parsed?

Comment: I am passing the DisplayTop to a Storedproc to fetch the top DisplayTop number of rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use `UInt32.TryParse(DisplayTop, out defaultTop)`?

This will return true if the number is 0 or positive, and false if negative.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
int defaultTop;
var isValidInt = Int32.TryParse(DisplayTop, out defaultTop);
displayTop = isValidInt && defaultTop >= 0 ? defaultTop : 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with TryParse alone, you will have to check the value of `defaultTop` independently. If you want it all in a single line you can try:

```
displayTop = ((Int32.TryParse(DisplayTop, out defaultTop) && defaultTop >= 0) ? defaultTop : 1000 );
```

Comment: Why do you convert it a second time? You can use `defaultTop` directly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - You're right! O the evils or blindly copy/pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.Max:

```
displayTop = Math.Max(1,(Int32.TryParse(DisplayTop, out defaultTop) ? Convert.ToInt32(DisplayTop) : 1000 ));
```

Granted, such a long expression is somewhat ugly, but it works.